# SQL Server: SUM values where other value is distcint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, subquery

I have a table of 2 columns, 1 is a id and other is a int.

How can i Sum the ints of unique Ids?

```
Eg 
Id Value
1 2
1 2
2 2
3 2
2 2
3 2

Result: 6 (2+2+2)
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. If you don't make all the `Value`s `2` we might have more of a chance of working out what you need. What are the desired results for [this sample data](http://pastebin.com/eh9yFpAC) and why?

Comment: your results do not make sense.  none of the ids in the data are unique.  and if you just mean you only want to sum the int value from one of them, when more than one exists, how do you decide which one to pick???  each might have a different value in the int column.

Comment: Apologies, just to clarify; the ids are not unique but the value associated to them is always the same so you can assume by distinction the ids you do not risk removing some data eg all id=1 will have value=2. it will always be reduced to 1=2, 2=2, 3=2

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that if an Id is present more than once in the table it has the same Value, then the following should work:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/027f7/3/0)

```
SELECT Sum(T.Value) FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT M.Id, M.Value FROM MyTable AS M
)AS T
```

But if the Value can be different amongst records where the Id is the same then you will have to go about it differently.  In the following example I am only pulling the top value:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c6176/1/0)

```
SELECT Sum(T.Value) FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT M.Id, 
  (
    SELECT TOP(1) MV.Value 
    FROM MyTable AS MV 
    WHERE MV.Id = M.Id 
    ORDER By MV.Value DESC
  ) AS Value 
  FROM MyTable AS M
)AS T
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(int)
from mytab t where not exists
   (select * from mytab 
    where id = t.id
    group by id
    having count(*) > 1)
```